# OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'io.excel.zip.reader'"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge multiple *.xlsx.zip* files into one but this error keeps on coming up.

Now, firstly I am using glob.glob for selecting the files (works perfectly)

```
stock_files = glob.glob('*/*.xlsx.zip', recursive=True)
stock_files
```

And then when I try to merge using this code

```
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in stock_files]
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0],header=None, index_col=None) for x in excels]
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]
```

I get this error in return:

```
OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'io.excel.zip.reader'"
```

Do I have to unzip the files first? because it does work with unzipped files but my data sample is massive and I would rather prefer not wasting time with unzipping the files. Is there a way to do it without unzipping? Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to SO! you would need a nested for loop for that because you have to check if multiple sheets within each file. please, as a beginner, don't try to attempt this with a nested for loop in a list-comprehension. please just attempt with normal for loops.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error a lot, it is usually triggered by a corrupted file, usually '.xlsx'. As far as I'm aware I have never encountered it or a similar error with csv or any other table file type.

I have always assumed the cause of the corruption was having the file open in pandas during the execution of a script which was terminated via keyboard interrupt. I have no idea why that would cause it but that's just my assumption.

One thing I learned from this error is that it is a bad idea to unnecessarily open your spreadsheet resources with pandas when you don't need them. When I encountered this era it was at a time where I had a utils file called spreadsheets.py which would open all of my spreadsheets so that I could import them from else where. Instead of